# camel serialize json in dead letter queue

Tags: java, json, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I have to stock my object (CcRequest) in a DeadLetterQueue with Json format.

How it is possible ?

Here my simple context :

```
<camelContext id="el1DMRCamelContext" autoStartup="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" >

    <template id="producerTemplate" />

    <!-- Routes -->
    <route id="createCcProcessorRoute" errorHandlerRef="createCcErrorHandler" >
        <from uri="activemq:queue:createCc" />
        <process ref="createCcProcessor" />
    </route>
</camelContext>

<bean id="createCcErrorHandler" class="org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder" >
    <property name="deadLetterUri" value="activemq:queue:createCcDLQ" />
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicy" />
</bean>
```

I would like my object (CcRequest stocked in the body of the exchange) in my activemq:queue:createCcDLQ to be in Json format instead of binaries.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not classify what you want to do as a dead letter handler. Dead letter is usually just moving/redelivery of the original message.

It is pretty simple you use the excetion clause instead.

```
<dataFormats>
    <json id="jsonFormat" library="Jackson"/>
</dataFormats>


<onException>
  <exception>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception>
  <marshal ref="jsonFormat"/>
  <to uri="activemq:queue:createCcDLQ"/>
</onException>
```

[Camel Exception Clause docs](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html)

[Camel JSON docs](http://camel.apache.org/json)